# How to order an ndb query by a repeated field that can be empty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have an ndb model with a repeated property:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):

  foo = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)
```

I want to do an inequality filter on `foo`, which means that I need to order by `foo`:

```
query = MyModel.query()
query = query.filter(MyModel.foo != my_key)
# I don't actually care about doing this, but I have to because of the inequality filter.
query = query.order(MyModel.foo)
```

I want the query to include entities where foo is empty.  It works if I put a dummy field into foo:

```
def _pre_put_hook(self):
  if not self.foo:
    self.foo.append(ndb.Key('Dummy Kind', 'Dummy ID'))
```

But that doesn't seem like a clean way to do this.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the Datastore stores properties with `repeated=True` in it's indices, it [stores one row for each value](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown#anc-entitiesbyproperty). What this means is that if you have an empty repeated property, it will not show up in your EntitiesByProperty index. This means it isn't possible to query for an empty repeated property.

There are a couple of options, but they each have their own tradeoff:

### Add a dummy value.

This method you suggested has the benefit that your existing query will give you the desired results. However, you have to deal with cleaning up the dummy key when you go to add real data.

### Use a `ComputedProperty`.

You could add a new property for the size of the foo property:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
  foo = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)
  foo_len = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: len(self.foo))
```

However, to get entities that have a `foo` value that doesn't match `my_key` or are empty, you'll have to write two queries to get the results:

```
ndb.gql("SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE foo != :1", my_key)
ndb.gql("SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE foo_len == :1" 0)
```

Note that if `foo` were not repeated, having the following query would give you the desired results:

```
ndb.gql("SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE foo != :1", my_key)
```

Even without the empty list case, you need to be careful when using repeated properties. In particular, only one of the repeated properties has to match your key. So a model as defined below will still match your query since `my_key2 != my_key`:

```
MyModel(foo=[my_key, my_key2])
```